# How do I (efficiently) output a GNU Make 3.81 "dictionary" to a file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a "dictionary" of items in GNU make.

```
MY_KEYS:=foo bar baz
foo_VALUE:=thing1
bar_VALUE:=thing2
baz_VALUE:=thing3
```

I want this dictionary of items output to a file so that it looks like so...

```
foo=thing1
bar=thing2
baz=thing3
```

**Difficulty**:  The "real" dictionary is a few kb in size, and exhausts command line limits on Windows.

My current, inefficient implementation ends up spawning far too many sh.exe processes, and ends up taking almost 20 seconds to emit just a few kb worth of data.

```
#Slow implementation
define NEWLINE


endef

list.txt:
    @printf '' > $@
    @$(foreach key,$(MY_KEYS), \
       printf '$(key)=$($(key)_VALUE)\n' >> $@ $(NEWLINE) )
```

The $(file) function isn't available in GNU make 3.81 either, as that would be the "obvious" fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could slice your list of keys into sublists that fit on the command line:

```
slice?=2
count?=3

$(shell echo -n 'MY_KEYS:=' > a.txt)
$(shell for i in `seq $(count)` ; do echo -n foo$$i' ' >> a.txt ; done)
$(shell echo >> a.txt)
$(shell for i in `seq $(count)` ; do echo foo$${i}_VALUE:=thing$$i >> a.txt ; done)

include a.txt

slices:=$(shell seq 1 $(slice) $(words $(MY_KEYS)))

define NEWLINE


endef

list.txt:
        @echo -n > $@
        @$(foreach s, $(slices), $(foreach key, $(wordlist $(s), $(shell echo $$(( $(s)+$(slice)-1 )) ), $(MY_KEYS)), echo $(key)=$($(key)_VALUE) >> $@ ; ) ${NEWLINE})
```

For instance, on my system the limit is somewhere between 10K and 100K keys:

```
x@vb:/tmp$ rm -f list.txt ; time make slice=100000 count=100000 list.txt 
make: execvp: /bin/sh: Argument list too long
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'list.txt' failed
make: *** [list.txt] Error 127

real    0m4.366s
user    0m1.452s
sys 0m2.772s
```

slicing into 10K sub-lists works and is still reasonably fast:

```
x@vb:/tmp$ rm -f list.txt ; time make slice=10000 count=100000 list.txt 

real    0m10.034s
user    0m3.852s
sys 0m5.788s
```

Answer (score 0):

*Make* will normally execute a command directly and not involve the shell.
Those `>>` redirections in your recipe however cause *make* to pass the recipe to an actual shell.
First speed-up then would be to avoid the shell metacharacters in the recipe,
halving the number of forks.

Recursive make with a single redirection fits the bill here.
A sketch:

```
.PHONY: dump
dump:
    $(foreach _,${MY_KEYS},echo $_=${$__VALUE}${NEWLINE})

list.txt:
    ${MAKE} -s dump >$@
```

This halves the number of forks c.f. the naive version.

All the `dump` rule does though is to echo something.
But *make* does that anyway
(in fact we added the `-s` flag to stop this).

We can use this to our advantage and avoid *all* the forks.
The `-n` flag will get *make* to do the echoing,
and not involve the shell.

```
.PHONY: dump
dump:
    $(foreach _,${MY_KEYS},$_=${$__VALUE}${NEWLINE})

list.txt:
    ${MAKE} -s -n dump >$@
```

Pow!

But yeah, upgrade your *make*.
This is so 20th century ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't that require me to export all of my keys and values?  Doesn't exporting them put them in the environment, possibly triggering resource exhaustion?

Comment: @user13521 No, there is no interaction with the shell, none at all. In the last formulation, we ask _make_ to make `dump`. At this point _make_ needs to generate the shell commands, so it expands the recipe. The `$(foreach …)` expands into the required output. Note that this is probably not valid shell syntax. However, since we run _make_ with `-n`, this is never passed to the shell. Phew. _Make_ does dutifully echo what it would have passed to the shell on stdout though. Job done. In milliseconds to boot.